# How to create a Powershell Script for Security Options within secpol.msc

Tags: powershell, windows-10, local-security-policy

Does anyone know how to create a Powershell script
(that I can add to a batch file) to disable the Windows-10 secpol.msc option:
 "User Account Control: Run all administrators in Admin Approval Mode"

I can already complete this action manually via the following actions:
Start -> run -> secpol.msc -> Expand Local Policies and then, expand security options ->
Scroll down to:
"User Account Control: Run all administrators in Admin Approval Mode" 
and select: disabled -> Click the button "Apply" and then, click on "OK".
However, I foresee this taking a while on multiple computers that we are testing (alongside other commands), so, I'm trying to create a batch file of powershell commands to help me during this test period.

If you can explain the basic guidelines - I would appreciate it.
- from this: I should be able to repeat it for some other options.

For context: Using this as a temp. workaround for older applications running in windows-10 (whilst searching for new replacements).

Thank you in advance for all future assistance and guidance provided.